# I can't find out how to run replace() correctly

Tags: javascript

I was trying to run the replace command, but an error occurred:"Uncaught TypeError: variable2.replaceAll is not a function"

Here's what I tried:

```js
variable2="blah,blah,blah12345";
variable1=variable2.replaceAll(/\D/g,'');
console.log(variable1);
```

I thought varible2 would equal "12345" but instead I got the error: "Uncaught TypeError: varible2.replaceAll is not a function".

Comment: Where are you running this, exactly?  Browser?  Node.js?  What versions?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility You can check the supported version nodejs, browser here.

Answer (score 4):

You can just remove the `All` from `replaceAll` as the `g` in `/\D/g`already represents the same functionality - see following snippet which returns `12345`

```js
const variable2 = "blah,blah,blah12345";
const variable1 = variable2.replace(/\D/g,'');
console.log(variable1);
```

Answer (score 4):

function replaceAll is only available in Node version 15 and above.

[Check the version compatibility of replaceAll here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Typescript, please do the following in your tsconfig.json

```js
{
    ...,
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...,
        "lib": [
          ...,
          "ES2021.String"
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried running your code in Typescript playground and it is showing the same error when running in ES2020 version or lower. The replaceAll method in String is supported from ES2021.

Answer (score -1):

If you use javascript, you can change the code as follows

```js
const variable2 = "blah,blah,blah12345";
const variable1 = variable2.replaceAll(/\D/g,'');
console.log(variable1);
```

Then you can get the results `12345`.

Comment: it's 2023, don't use `var`. Use `let` or since we're never rebinding in this code, `const`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mainly use 'let' or 'const' when declaring new variables. In this demonstration, I do not know the runtime environment of the questioner, so I use 'var' to declare variables.

Comment: of course you do: the question is tagged with "javascript" so we teach modern JS and make sure not to teach legacy JS anymore (we'll leave that for the ancient tutorials people still, unfortunately, find online and use)

Answer (score -2):

You're probably using some kind of strict script parser, and using `var2` wrongly somewhere. Below it is being outputted in a non-strict mode. Notice that the variable value, the function itself, and the return of that function are all being outputted correctly. Make sure if you want the output of a function performed on it, to use choice 3. If you want just the raw value, use choice 1.

```js
const var2 = "blah,blah,blah12345";
const var1 = var2.replaceAll(/\D/g,'');
console.log(var2, var2.replaceAll, var2.replaceAll(/\D/g,''));
```

Answer (score -2):

The following code will work parfectly

```
variable2 = "blah,blah,blah12345"; variable1 = variable2.replaceAll(/\D/g, '');
```

console.log(variable1);